# laravel config file retun null in config folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a config file called **fcm.php** in **config** folder in laravel. The file looks like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('FCM_PROTOCOL', 'http'),
    'log_enabled' => true,

    'http' => [
        'server_key' => config('app.fcm_mode') == 'user' ? env('FCM_SERVER_KEY', 'Your FCM server key') : env('FCM_DELIVERY_SERVER_KEY', 'Your FCM server key'),
        'sender_id' => config('app.fcm_mode') == 'user' ? env('FCM_SENDER_ID', 'Your sender id') : env('FCM_DELIVERY_SENDER_ID', 'Your sender id'),
        'server_send_url' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        'server_group_url' => 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
        'timeout' => 30.0, // in second
    ],
];
```

It works properly in my localhost(I vendor:publish fcm.php config file), But in a shared host, config('app') return null in this file(config/fcm.php)

What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: For what `config('app')` is?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay config('app.fcm_mode') is null, also config('app') is null

Comment: The code you have posted in your question is your fcm.php file?

Comment: Where you have declared `fcm_mode` ?

Comment: are you there? You got it solved?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay it is in my config/app.php file

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay it work properly in localhost, but not work in shared host

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `config()` from inside of config files. See this for more info: https://blog.maqe.com/dont-use-laravel-s-config-inside-config-files-40e2c8207225

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it through:

```
config('fcm.log_enabled')
```